# PostgreSQL admin tool behind nginx

Tags: postgresql, webapps, pgadmin

I have a VPS with PostgreSQL installed. I have a nginx setup with a some reverse proxies to different tools, grafana, Node.js sites and so on. I'm trying to setup PostgreSQL right now, and I just can't work out the web based admin tool, one that is reachable from outside.

I tried installing normal pgAdmin with Apache2 hosting, but that obviously conflicted with nginx. I've tried to find a good guide on pgAdmin behind a nginx reverse proxy, but the only one I found (https://github.com/rbernardes/nginx-pgadmin) did not work at all when I tried to run the py config script. I could dive into that harder, but my point is; pgAdmin does not seem to play well with nginx, and I thought there must be a valid web based alternative? But it seems a bit dry here...

Can anybody shed some light on this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is much simpler way:

First Install **PgAdmin** from `ftp.postgresql.org` repository:

```bsh
curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/focal pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pgadmin4
```

Here is when the Fun part begins, Open `sudo vim /etc/apache2/ports.conf` and comment out **80** and **443** ports and add new port `5050` or any port you desire.
[apache ports.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hVP8.png)

Now lets check `sudo vim /etc/apache2/conf-available/pgadmin4.conf` this is where pgadmin runs from `[WSGI][2]`.

Remove the `pgadmin` front IN of `WSGIScriptAlias` an the code should look like this.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess pgadmin processes=1 threads=25 python-home=/usr/pgadmin4/venv
WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.wsgi

<Directory /usr/pgadmin4/web/>
    WSGIProcessGroup pgadmin
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

*[comment]: Do not add more processes (you will get `CSRF` error), add more **threads** If you whant.*

Now lets check our VirtualHost `sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`, just pass the ssl certificate files and some basic stuff (remember to serve port 5050 or whatever port you chowsen):

```
<VirtualHost *:5050>
  ServerAdmin you@your.domain

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/pub.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/private/perv.key
  ErrorDocument 404 "looks like you not found the page :("
  ErrorDocument 403 "It's Forbidden!"
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

*[Note]: remember to `sudo a2enmod ssl`, If you are using ssl*.

Now complete your **PgAdmin** installation, set the password and enable `WSGI` module.

```bsh
sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh
```

Check if everything is alright and restart the apache service.

```bsh
sudo apachectl -t
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Lets see our beloved `nginx`, It's a simple config but quite unbreakable:)

```
server {
  listen  443 ssl http2;
  server_name  your.domain.com;

  ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/pub.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/perv.key;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://your.domain.com:5050;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  }

}
```

At the end restart the `Nginx`.

```bsh
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

---

Thanks [tecadmin](https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-pgadmin4-on-ubuntu-20-04/) for installing **PgAdmin** on **Ubuntu**.

Answer (score 1):

> tried installing normal pgAdmin with Apache2 hosting, but that obv. conflicted with nginx

it won't if you configure Apache2 to listen to different port that nginx didn't use.

> pgAdmin does not seem to play well with nginx

install and [configure uWSGI with pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/server_deployment.html) app, then configure nginx to use [`uwsgi_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_pass) to communicate to uWSGI.

---

> *Edit 2020-05-10: More details and information*

You got two solutions here, either use nginx + `uwsgi_pass`, or Apache httpd + mod_proxy_wsgi. Let's delve into both.

## Prerequisites

1. Python and Python development headers

   Install Python and its compatible development headers, preferably [Python >=3.6](https://devguide.python.org/#status-of-python-branches). PCRE 3 libraries are required for uwsgi to handle regex routings.

> ```
> $ sudo apt-get update && apt-get -y install build-essential python3 python3-dev libpcre3-dev libpcre3
> ```

2. Python virtual environment

   Install your pgAdmin on a virtual environment, whether it's [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), [`conda`](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/), anything even; just to make sure that your OS package manager won't interfere with your python environments (versions, packages, etc).

   If you're using `venv`, it should be something like

> ```
> $ cd /path/to/working_directory
>
> # Install virtual environment on .env, and activate it.
> $ python3 -m venv .env
> $ source .env/bin/activate
>
> # upgrade existing pip packages, and install wheel.
> (.env) $ pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
> (.env) $ pip install wheel
>
> # install pgAdmin 4.21
> (.env) $ pip install https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v4.21/pip/pgadmin4-4.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> ```

## uWSGI and pgAdmin

#### uWSGI Installation

To let your webserver connect to pgAdmin, you'll use WSGI or HTTP server. pgAdmin supports [uWSGI](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/server_deployment.html#standalone-uwsgi-configuration) and [Gunicorn](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/server_deployment.html#standalone-gunicorn-configuration).

Here, we'll use uWSGI, but if you're using another WSGI server, just make sure that it's listening at UNIX socket `/tmp/wsgi/pgadmin.sock`

First, you'll need to install uWSGI. You can install uWSGI with `apt-get` or with `pip`.

Both are fine; but with `pip`, you'll need to write your own service file; and with `apt-get`, you'll need to accept you're using older version of uWSGI. We'll install both, using Ubuntu-distributed service file and pip-distributed latest version `uwsgi` binary

> ```
> Install Ubuntu-distributed uwsgi
> $ sudo apt-get -y install uwsgi
>
> Install pip-distributed uwsgi
> $ source /path/to/working_directory/.env/bin/activate
> (.env) $ pip install uwsgi
>
> # Ubuntu-distributed version
> (.env) $ /usr/bin/uwsgi --version
> 2.0.15-debian
>
> # pip-distributed version
> (.env) $ uwsgi --version
> 2.0.18
>
> # service file
> (.env) $ ls /etc/init.d/uwsgi
> /etc/init.d/uwsgi
> ```

#### pgAdmin Installation

Next, we're setting pgAdmin up for uWSGI. You'll need to get into our virtual environment again. We're roughly following [this pgAdmin official guide](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/server_deployment.html#python).

First, create a local configuration.

> ```
> $ cd /path/to/working_directory/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4
> $ cp config.py config_local.py
> $ vim config_local.py
> ```

Note that you can follow pgAdmin's documentation, but we can just edit `DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/pgadmin'` to anything sensible, because everything else will refer to `DATA_DIR`. Here, we use `/path/to/working_directory/lib`

Next, create pgAdmin's required directories

> ```
> $ sudo mkdir -p /var/log/pgadmin
> $ mkdir /path/to/working_directory/lib
> ```

`/var/log/pgadmin` and `DATA_DIR` should be fully controlled by uWSGI, because pgAdmin will be running under uWSGI. Here, we'll be using `www-data` as uWSGI user and group.

> ```
> $ sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/log/pgadmin /path/to/working_directory/lib
> ```

Note that we need to allow writes to `/var/log/pgadmin` and `DATA_DIR` to let it set up. We only let it be writable by our user now, and we will fix this permission later.

> ```
> $ sudo chmod 777 /var/log/pgadmin /path/to/working_directory/lib
> ```

Enter our virtual environment and run pgAdmin's `setup.py`.

> ```
> $ source /path/to/working_directory/.env/bin/activate
> (.env) $ cd /path/to/working_directory/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4
> (.env) $ python setup.py
> ```

Follow setup instructions until it's complete, and take note of your email and password created here.

Next, fix `/var/log/pgadmin` and `DATA_DIR` permissions.

> ```
> $ chmod 755 /var/log/pgadmin /path/to/working_directory/lib
> $ chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/pgadmin /path/to/working_directory/lib
> ```

pgAdmin should be completely set up by now.

#### Integrating uWSGI and pgAdmin

Now, we're ready to integrate pgAdmin and uWSGI, creating WSGI server that listens at UNIX socket `/tmp/wsgi/pgadmin.sock`.

First, using your favorite editor, create a uWSGI configuration file in `/etc/uwsgi/apps-available`. Let's call it `pgadmin.ini`.

> ```
> $ sudo vim /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/pgadmin.ini
> ```

It should contain at least:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/wsgi/pgadmin.sock
chdir = /path/to/working_directory/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4
manage-script-name = true
venv = /path/to/working_directory/.env/
master = true
processes = 1
threads = 4
mount = /=pgAdmin4:app
log-format = %(addr) - %(user) [%(ltime)] "%(method) %(uri) %(proto)" %(status) %(size) "%(referer)" "%(uagent)"
logger = file:/tmp/wsgi/pgadmin-access.log
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
```

create required directories, and enable our pgAdmin uWSGI app

> ```
> $ sudo mkdir -p /tmp/wsgi
> $ sudo chown www-data:www-data /tmp/wsgi
> $ sudo ln -s /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/pgadmin.ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/pgadmin.ini
> ```

copy default uWSGI file to another service file, and edit it to use pip-installed uWSGI binary.

> ```
> $ sudo cp /etc/init.d/uwsgi /etc/init.d/uwsgi-venv
> $ vim /etc/init.d/uwsgi-venv
> # replace DAEMON="/usr/bin/uwsgi" to DAEMON="/path/to/working_directory/.env/bin/uwsgi
> ```

uWSGI configuration should be done.

Now, try to start uWSGI.

> ```
> $ sudo service uwsgi-venv start pgadmin
> ```

Here, `pgadmin` refers to what we've soft-linked in `/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled` before. If you linked it as `pgadmin.ini`, you'll use `pgadmin`.

Check if uWSGI is running.

> ```
> $ ps -eF | grep uwsgi
> www-data 10582     1  2 32144 91480   0 03:56 ?        00:00:03 /path/to/working_directory/.env/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/pgadmin.ini --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi/app/pgadmin.log
> www-data 10593 10582  0 87443  2640   0 03:56 ?        00:00:00 /path/to/working_directory/.env/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/pgadmin.ini --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi/app/pgadmin.log
> ```

## nginx and uWSGI

If you haven't installed nginx, install it with `apt-get`.

> ```
> $ sudo apt-get -y install nginx
> ```

If you have already installed nginx, you may need to adjust some configurations. Let me know if you had any trouble then.

Next, let's configure nginx so that it'll pass any requests to uWSGI we configured earlier.

In `/etc/nginx/sites-available` directory, create a new nginx configuration file. Here, we're using `pgadmin.local` as virtual hostname.

> ```
> $ sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/pgadmin.conf
> ```

This configuration file should look at least like this:

> ```
> server {
>     listen 80;
>     server_name pgadmin.local;
>
>     location / {
>         include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
>         uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/wsgi/pgadmin.sock;
>     }
> }
> ```

If you need it to listen to other port, change `listen 80;` to `listen <your_port>;`.

Enable this configuration.

> ```
> $ sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/pgadmin.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/pgadmin.conf
> ```

Test and reload your new nginx configuration.

> ```
>  $ sudo nginx -t && sudo service nginx reload
> ```

Depending on your configuration, you may need to configure your firewall after this, but after that, you can browse to your configured virtual host with your favorite browser.

> ```
>  $ firefox http://pgadmin.local
> ```

## httpd and uWSGI

There's not a lot of difference between httpd and nginx configuration here, you just need to forward http request as WSGI request to WSGI server backend, in this case, using mod_proxy_wsgi.

Install httpd first if you haven't installed it yet.

> ```
> $ sudo apt-get -y install apache2 apache2-utils
> ```

If you have already installed httpd, you may need to adjust some configurations. Let me know if you had any trouble then.

Don't forget to install mod-proxy and mod-proxy-uwsgi, as both these modules are required.

> ```
> $ sudo apt-get -y install libapache2-mod-proxy-uwsgi
> ```

Next, let's configure httpd to pass any requests to uWSGI we configured earlier.

In `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory, create a new virtual host configuration file. Here, we're using `pgadmin.local` as virtual hostname.

> ```
> $ sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/pgadmin.conf
> ```

This configuration file should look at least like this:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   ServerName pgadmin.local
>   ProxyRequests off
>   ProxyPass "/" "unix:/tmp/wsgi/pgadmin.sock|uwsgi://localhost/"
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

If you need it to listen to other port, you'll need a few changes.

1. Change `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost *:<your_port>>`
2. In `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, remove all irrelevant `Listen`s including those under `<IfModule>`s, and add `Listen <your_port>`.
3. If you still have default site enabled, disable it with `a2dissite`.

Enable this configuration.

> ```
> $ sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/pgadmin.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/pgadmin.conf
> ```

Enable mod_proxy and mod_proxy_uwsgi

> ```
> $ sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_uwsgi
> ```

Test and reload your new httpd configuration.

> ```
> $ sudo apachectl configtest && sudo service apache2 reload
> ```

Depending on your configuration, you may need to configure your firewall after this, but after that, you can browse to your configured virtual host with your favorite browser.

> ```
>  $ firefox http://pgadmin.local
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your first answer @mforsetti. It is preferable to give at least some brief instructions and maybe a link as to where people can do what you suggest that they do.

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently not working in this part, but will return to it soon. But I remember trying something like what you are suggesting and having lots of troubles. When I revisit it I will try it again and give you the bounty if it works. But better instructions by some one would really be appreciated!

Edit, saw the time limit of 24 hours until my bounty is removed anyway... Seems like this issue is a bit tricky since I have not found any easy guides or solutions. Will consider it more today.

Comment: @Kurankat and OP, I've added some instructions to follow. You may follow that or probably adjust that according to your site. Give me a nudge if you need anything to ask, and sorry about that previous lousy answer.

Comment: Holy smokes, that is a great answer! I'm going to follow it as soon as I have time and pay another 75 rep just to give you a new bounty since the last one expired. I hope it works well, thanks you for your time so far!